# Facing issue while calling model summary keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to neural networks. I am trying to build `CON2D + LSTM` to recognize gestures from images. I have written below code:

```
input_shape = (120, 120, 3) // Having 120x120 images in RGB 3 channel
num_classes = 5 //Have to detect 5 gestures

model = Sequential()
# First conv, 32
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D((32), (3,3), input_shape = input_shape)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D((32), (3,3))))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

# Second conv, 64
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D((64), (3, 3))))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20)))

#configure LSTM
model.add(LSTM(20, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(num_classes)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
print (model.summary())
```

I am getting below error after calling `model.summary()`

```
ValueError: This model has never been called, thus its weights have not yet been created, so no summary can be displayed. Build the model first (e.g. by calling it on some test data).
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: you don't need to pass `model.summary()` to `print` function. Just call `model.summary()` and it'll print it to console.

Answer (score 0):

That's funny... What versions of TF and Keras are you using?

This would be common in a subclassed model, but sounds new to me in a `Sequential` model.

Just follow the instructions in the error:

```
test_predictions = model.predict(numpy.zeros((1,) + input_shape))
model.summary()
```